# Creating a function that takes in a text file as an argument

Tags: c#, text-files

I will admit, I am learning C#. I know what I want to do, it's just a matter of the syntax and calling the right "stuff" as it were.

Essentially, I want to create a function that takes in two arguments:

1. A Text File
2. A String

From what I have been reading and trying to figure out, there are a lot of different methods to Read in text files and do stuff, but I haven't come across a way that actually takes one in as an argument. I know how to create functions in C# that take in data types of particular types, like bool, string, int, decimal, etc.

So, basically it's like this (My Dream, so to say)

```
protected bool FindWordInFile((textfile), string word_to_find) //Generic Function that takes in a word list file as an argument and a search word and returns if there is a match or not
{
      //Do stuff
      bool FoundIt = false;
      return FoundIt;
 }
```

Now, the reason I want to do it like this is I have different text files I will want to use to find things, instead of creating separate functions for each of the types of search I want to do.

So, conceivably, I could do:

```
bool IsThereGoodStuff = FindWordInFile("goodstuff.txt", "awesome");
bool IsThereBadStuff = FindWordInFile("badstuff.txt", "terrible");
```

Alternatively, I could just create an array from a file and pass the array as an argument, but I would rather not do that. The array wouldn't be that big, given the size of the text files, or I could convert the contents of the text file into a string and pass that. Either way, I want to avoid it.

I've tried mucking around with this a way to create a StreamReader Object, but I haven't found a way to pass that an argument to a function. If there's a way to do that, great!

```
StreamReader goodwordsfile = new StreamReader("c:\\wordfilelib\\goodwords.txt");
```

But, ideally, I just want to pass the damn file to the function.

Thank you in advance for any help. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you are going to read files of same type (plain text files eg.) I suggest you to pass the physical path of the file to the method and read the file inside. This is better for some reasons.

Comment: I believe `File.ReadAllText(string filename)` is [what you're after](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It is much cleaner to include the name of the file inside the method and then handle any streams or file operations in side it, given a good parameter name it should be clear that you expect a filename, and can also check that this file exists

Comment: Just pass the name of the file as a parameter and open the file inside that function. We should always try to keep the scope of large variables as limited as possible.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: reading *all text* `File.ReadAllText` could be expensive for big files, I'd recommend `File.ReadLines(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I recommend you try using ***Linq***? e.g.:

```
 Boolean found = File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")               // <- Your file name
   .Any(line => line.Contains(word_to_find)); // <- Word to find
```

With Linq you don't need any methods to implement and have one line solution.

EDIT: in case that you have to find out *words*, e.g. `"the"`, but not `"then"` you can modify the solution by using *regular expressions* instead of simple `Contains()`:

```
  Boolean found = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")               
    .Any(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, @"(^|\W)" + word_to_find + @"($|\W)"));
```

Comment: So this probably is the best approach, although I would still put that one line into a separate method to avoid code repetition and to make it more readable (i.e. `if (FileContainsWord(filename, word))` is probably easier to read than the using the Linq directly).

Comment: This approach worked best. Other solutions had problems evaluating properly because what would happen is:

good things come to great people.

The function would take in the word "good" and the bool value came back True. That's what it's supposed to do.

But when it ran into the word "things", it evaluated to False, and then all other words afterwards came up False, even if they WERE supposed to evaluate to true. Not quite understand why that happened...trying to figure it out.

Comment: This answer did not address the question which is about the parameter type for FindInWord function.  The implementation is also incorrect.  It has false positives ie. word to find "the" and file has a line containing the word "then".  It also implies that you have to read the whole file every time for every word you need to find.

Comment: @Mark Menchavez: in case that a *word* (not A *string partA) is required to be found the initial Linq can be modified by using *regular expression* instead of `Contains()` (see my edit)

Comment: I removed my downvote @Dmitry.  However, I still have the opinion that shorter codes are not necessarily better especially for beginners like MichaelKnowsNothing.  Fluent API has its uses but I think this is not a good use case.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the FileInfo class as an argument to your function. This signifies to your caller that indeed you are expecting a file rather than the name of the file or the content of the file.

Comment: I wish more libraries took that approach. There is no excuse for passing around naked strings to represent file names with full paths.

Answer (score 2):

To pass a text file into a method, you need an *object* that can represent the text file. As you said, you could use a `String` object with the path to the file, but there are alternatives:

- [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx): This represents the file and its metadata, but not its content. It has methods to open a `Stream` with the file's data.
- [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream%.aspx): This represents the file's data as a stream of *bytes*. It has methods to read bytes from the file.
- [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx): This is a reader object that wraps a `Stream` and allows you to read characters (instead of bytes).

Look at the documentation for each to see whether it suits your needs and how to use it.

---

Whichever you choose, you have to change your `FindWordInFile` method to accept an object of the specified type. For example, using a `StreamReader`:

```
protected bool FindWordInFile(StreamReader textfileReader, string wordToFind)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Note how the *type of object* (`StreamReader` in this case) is specified before the parameter name in the method's signature (the line with the method's name).

---

A short example reading from a `StreamReader`:

```
using System.IO;

class MyClass
{
    protected bool FindWordInFile(StreamReader textfileReader, string wordToFind)
    {
        // Read the first line.
        string line = textfileReader.ReadLine();

        // The current line must not be null,
        // or we've reached the end of the file.
        while (line != null)
        {
            // TODO: Go find your word in the current line.

            // Read the next line.
            line = textfileReader.ReadLine();
        }

        // We didn't find the word in the file.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Instead of writing `System.IO.StreamReader` everywhere, you can put the line `using System.IO` at the top of your C# file and write just `StreamReader` everywhere in the file. C# then knows to look in `System.IO` to find `StreamReader`.

Comment: I think something like this is the best approach, not least because it makes it much easier to unit test the method. (I know you could open a file in the method and still unit test it, but that would mean that the unit test would have to create or have available a file in the test system, which is generally frowned upon for unit tests.) As an alternative to passing in a `StreamReader` you could pass in an `IEnumerable<string>` which can be obtained from a call to `File.ReadLines()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass in an entire file to the method (unless you read it as a string and you pass that string).

I think that the best way to do what you are after is to pass in the file path as parameter:

```
protected bool FindWordInFile(string filePath, string word_to_find)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the `Stream` object directly, so you would do:

```
protected bool FindWordInFile(StreamReader sr, string word_to_find)
{
    ...
}
```

And call it like so:

```
foreach(string filePath in filePaths)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        FindWordInFile(sr, ...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think passing the `StreamReader` as a parameter is a good choice.

```
protected bool FindWordInFile(StreamReader reader, string word_to_find))
```

should do the trick.

Depending on your overall solution, you can also:

1. Read the file into a string (or array or whatever) and pass the string to the method.
2. Pass the path of the file to the method and read the file there.

Comment: If you're passing a `StreamReader` as a parameter, then the function name should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in right track.
Your code is good, and have nothing extra to do.

for test file: pass its path to the function
Then open that file, read it line by line or complete file inside the function code block and then find the work you want to find.

```
    using System.IO;
    public bool findText(string filePath, string wordToFind)
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        if (content.Contains(wordToFind))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `File.ReadAllText()` - reading *all the text* - could be *very expensive* esp. for big files. Another issue is that you can have `OutOfMemory` exception thrown for such files

Comment: All are very good suggestions. I'm trying things out, but all of the suggestions are helping very much.

And to note, these text files are not large at all. At most, each will be 50 words. I don't want to do XML because of the overhead, and it's not really structured data that you would see in a Database. These are small files. :D

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Definetly if its large its intelligent to read line by line. But rather than passing a stream, or any other other kind of object as parameter I will always suggest to pass file path

Answer (score 0):

Send text file as array of bytes `byte[]` for 1st parameter or convert it while loading to `string`. `Stream` is the other option.